# Android : OpenCv comparing two images issue

Tags: java, android, opencv

I want to compare two image in percent in android , here is my codes

```
Mat img1 = Highgui.imread("storage/external_SD/a.png");
Mat img2 = Highgui.imread("storage/external_SD/b.png");
MatOfKeyPoint keypoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
MatOfKeyPoint keypoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint();
Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();

//Definition of ORB keypoint detector and descriptor extractors
FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB); 
DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);

//Detect keypoints
detector.detect(img1, keypoints1);
detector.detect(img2, keypoints2);  
//Extract descriptors
extractor.compute(img1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
extractor.compute(img2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

//Definition of descriptor matcher
DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING);

//Match points of two images
MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2 ,matches);
```

For example my method out put should be :

```
Images is 90% same
```

But i dont know what should i do after `matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2 ,matches);` method, can you please advise me ?

Comment: is this working?

Answer (score -2):

As I remember method `match()` must return value of `double` or `float`.
I did same thing with face comparison and I did (according to your case):

```
double value = matcher.match(descriptors1,descriptors2 ,matches);
```

There are 2 similar questions around this. Check it out. Must be useful.
[OpenCV filtering ORB matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24569386/opencv-filtering-orb-matches)
[OpenCV - Java - No match with 2 opposite images using DescriptorMatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860992/opencv-java-no-match-with-2-opposite-images-using-descriptormatcher)